# SQL DATEDIFF result differ from Excel in fraction of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

been struggling to find a way to work around this issue.

We are moving away from excel and adding calculations into SQL in fraction of hours by subtracting two dates.

The problem is our results in excel differ from SQL.

This is what we have in excel:

```
Change Date: 30/10/2018      
Change Time: 10:53

Service Date: 29/10/2018    
Service Time: 9:37      

The Formula in excel is: =((Change Date+Change Time)-(Service Date+Service Time))*24
```

The result in Fraction of hours is: **25.26666667**

The same data imported into SQL using DATEDIFF (syntax below):

```
datediff(second,CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,Service_Date,103) as smalldatetime) 
            + CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,Service_Time,103) as smalldatetime) as smalldatetime),
            CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,Change_Date,103) as smalldatetime) 
            + CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,Change_Time,103) as smalldatetime) as smalldatetime)) /3600.0
```

gives the result: **26.350000**

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this discrepancy?

Thanks heaps in advance,

Juliana

Comment: i do get the same value

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I didn't get difference as well. Also, in your case you don't need to cast the values to SMALLDATETIME. Check it without casting : DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, Service_Date, 103) + CONVERT(DATETIME, Service_Time, 103), CONVERT(DATETIME, Change_Date, 103) + CONVERT(DATETIME, Change_Time, 103)) / 3600.0

Comment: Please check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90ac1cbcfce19f176763760dd0590216)

Answer (score 0):

Check your inputs.  Your logic is correct, although it can be simplified.  Run the code sample below in SSMS for clarity.

```
declare @Service_Date varchar(max) = '30/10/2018'
declare @Service_Time varchar(max) = '10:53'

declare @Change_Date varchar(max) = '29/10/2018'
declare @Change_Time varchar(max) = '9:37'

--
-- Original 
--
select datediff(second,CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,@Service_Date,103) as smalldatetime) 
            + CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,@Service_Time,103) as smalldatetime) as smalldatetime),
            CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,@Change_Date,103) as smalldatetime) 
            + CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,@Change_Time,103) as smalldatetime) as smalldatetime)) /3600.0

--
-- Simplified - same result
--
select datediff(second,
    (CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Service_Date,103) + CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Service_Time,103)),
    (CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Change_Date,103) + CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Change_Time,103))) /3600.0

--
-- Simplfied - shows error is with inpuyts, not logic
--
set @Service_Time = '11:57'
set @Change_Time = '9:36'
select datediff(second,
    (CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Service_Date,103) + CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Service_Time,103)),
    (CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Change_Date,103) + CONVERT(smalldatetime,@Change_Time,103))) /3600.0
```